# AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'dev'

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, pycharm, xubuntu

Hy,
Yeah so, i am writing an python3 programm, that should send the content of an file to an LPC1758.
For testing i will write a simple string above USB. I use libusb1.0 ....

But every time i become the same error, even if i rename "dev" into "device" the error is the same.
--> AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'dev'<--

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.pb_send.clicked.connect(self.pb_send_clicked)
    self.pb_open.clicked.connect(self.pb_open_clicked)
    self.pb_exit.clicked.connect(self.pb_exit_clicked)


  # SEND button event handler
def pb_send_clicked(self):

    send = "Yo Man"

    bulk_out_ep = 0x05
    bulk_in_ep = 0x82
    interface = 0
    length = 30

    dev = usb.core.find(idVendor= 0xfefe, idProduct= 0x0001)
    cfg = usb.control.get_configuration(dev)            # get current configuration

    print(dev)


    if dev is None:
        self.USB_label.setText("Device not found !!!")
        raise ValueError('Device not found')
    else:
        self.USB_label.setText("Device found")
        found = 1

    if(cfg != 1):                                       # check if device is configured
        usb.DeviceHandle.setConfiguration(self, 1)

    usb.util.claim_interface(dev, interface)

    usb.DeviceHandle.bulkWrite(self,bulk_out_ep,send)
    print("wrote to estick")
    readData = usb.DeviceHandle.bulkRead(self, bulk_in_ep, length)
    print("read from estick: "+ readData)

    usb.util.release_interface(dev, interface)
```

This is what Stacktrace shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/workspace_Qt/ESS_project/ess_project.py", line 93, in pb_send_clicked
    readData = usb.DeviceHandle.bulkRead(self,endpoint=bulk_in_ep,size=length)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/usb/legacy.py", line 159, in bulkRead
    return self.dev.read(endpoint, size, self.__claimed_interface, timeout)
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'dev'
```

Comment: I don't think that the error is coming from the provided code, because I see nothing in this code that can cause the mentioned error. Please make sure that you have got that error from this piece of code by looking at the `stacktrace` and find the line number of the error.

Comment: this is what my stacktrace outputs:<br/>Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "/home/hummer/workspace_Qt/ESS_project/ess_project.py", line 93, in pb_send_clicked<br/>
    readData = usb.DeviceHandle.bulkRead(self,endpoint=bulk_in_ep,size=length)<br/>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/usb/legacy.py", line 159, in bulkRead<br/>
    return self.dev.read(endpoint, size, self.__claimed_interface, timeout)<br/>
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'dev'<br/>i have no idea what this means...

Answer (score 0):

`dev` is a member of the class `DeviceHandle` which is the type of the first parameter expected by the `setConfiguration` functions.

And `setConfiguration` expects 2 parameters instead of 1, because you are calling the method on the class `usb.DeviceHandle` instead of calling it on an object of type `usb.DeviceHandle`, you should use:

```
dev.setConfiguration(1)
```

(same thing for `bulkWrite` and `bulkRead`).

Also the `get_configuration` method returns a `Configuration` object instead of a number, so `cfg != 1` will always be true (this may work with `cfg.index != 1` instead but I'm not sure).

Comment: i have tried it but without success. When i remove the "self" attribute from bulkRead and buldWrite, i got an error that Attributes are missing... 
other ideas ?

Comment: @InvAdErZz I edited the answer. I wrongly assumed `usb.DeviceHandle` was one of your object and not a class.

Comment: Oh sorry.. good thing: now i am wiser  bad thing: problem is still there :(  what attributes can a device object have ??